# How to change Android Notification bar, but color system bar at the bottom a different color

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I am trying to stylize my application with notification bar tinting.
Unfortunately, when I color the notification bar, it colors the system bar (the bar with the home, back, and recent apps buttons at the bottom) the same color.

I am currently using the SystemBarTint library https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, this may not color the nav bar, but it gives me the desired result:

```
 tintManager.setNavigationBarTintEnabled(false);
```

This line set the nav bar to clear, which was my desired result.

I also found:

```
 tintManager.setNavigationBarTintColor(Color.BLACK);
```

which can set the nav bar to any color.

I am closing this question with this answer.